# Using mockito to test function that uses a context

Tags: android, mockito

```
Android Studio 2.1.2
```

I am trying to test `getJsonFromResource` which calls `loadNewsFeed`.
I want to be able to test 2 cases 1 where `loadNewsFeed` will return an empty string and the other where it will return some json string.

So I am trying to mock the `loadNewsFeed` function to return an empty string. However, when the concrete `getJsonFromResource` is called it will call the real `loadNewsFeed` and cause a null pointer exception.
This is what I have tried in my test comments explaining what I am doing:

```
@Test
public void shouldFailIfJSONStringIsEmpty() throws Exception {
    /* Mock Context class */
    Context context = mock(Context.class);
    /* initialize the concrete parseNewsFeed passing in the fake context */
    ParseNewsFeed parseNewsFeed = new ParseNewsFeed(context);
    /* Create a mock of the parseNewsFeed so a fake call to loadNewsFeed will return an empty string */
    ParseNewsFeed mockParseNewsFeed = mock(ParseNewsFeed.class);
    /* Mock the events that will be verified */
    ParseNewsFeedContract.Events<Status> mockEvents = mock(ParseNewsFeedContract.Events.class);

    /* Return an empty string when loadNewsFeed is called */
    when(mockParseNewsFeed.loadNewsFeed()).thenReturn("");

    /* Called the concrete getJsonFromResource */
    parseNewsFeed.getJsonFromResource(mockEvents);

    /* verify that onNewsFailure was called once and onNewsSuccess was never called */
    verify(mockEvents, times(1)).onNewsFailure(anyString());
    verify(mockEvents, never()).onNewsSuccess(any(Status.class));
}
```

This is the class I am trying to test.

```
public class ParseNewsFeed implements ParseNewsFeedContract {
    private Context mContext;

    public ParseNewsFeed(Context context) {
        if(context != null) {
            Timber.d("mContext != null");
            mContext = context;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the json from the local resource file and add to the cache to save loading each time
     * @return the json in string representation
     */
    @Override
    public void getJsonFromResource(Events<Status> events) {
        /* Get the json in string format */
        final String jsonString = loadNewsFeed();

        /* Check that is contains something */
        if(!jsonString.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                final Status status = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Status.class);
                if(status != null) {
                    Timber.d("url: %s", status.getResults().get(0).getMultimedia().get(0).getUrl());
                    events.onNewsSuccess(status);
                }
                else {
                    Timber.e("status == null");
                    events.onNewsFailure("Failed to get results from json");
                }
            }
            catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                Timber.e("Invalid JSON: %s", e.getMessage());
                events.onNewsFailure(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Opens and reads from the news_list and writes to a buffer
     * @return return the json representation as a string or a empty string for failure
     */
    public String loadNewsFeed() {
        InputStream inputStream = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.news_list);
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];

        try {
            InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
            int n;
            while ((n = bufferReader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }

            inputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioException) {
            return "";
        }

        return writer.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like  you want to have a `ParseNewsFeed` object where the `loadNewsFeed` method has been stubbed, but other methods work correctly.  The simplest way to get that would probably be to create a spy, something like

```
ParseNewsFeed spyParseNewsFeed = Mockito.spy(new ParseNewsFeed(context));
Mockito.doReturn("").when(spyParseNewsFeed).loadNewsFeed();
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the reason why your original code doesn't work is because there's no relationship between your two objects `parseNewsFeed` and `mockParseNewsFeed`, hence the stubbing that you do for the `mockParseNewsFeed` doesn't have any effect when you invoke `parseNewsFeed.getJsonFromResource(mockEvents)`. Using `spy` as David Wallace suggested would work, but if I were you, I would rewrite the code a bit differently to make it even easier to test.

One observation is that the code in `loadNewsFeed()` method doesn't seem to have a strong relationship with the `ParseNewsFeed` class, so I'd extract this code into an object (e.g. `NewsFeedLoader`), and then have this object as a dependency of `ParseNewsFeed` class. Then you can mock this `Loader` easily (return `""` or any string that you want when passing a `Context` and possibly the `R.raw.news_list` id as well). With this `Loader` class, you can even unit test it separately from the `ParseNewsFeed`, and being able to improve the `Loader` however you want to (e.g. a better way to read a raw resource) without affecting the `ParseNewsFeed` class.

Answer (score 5):

Use `when()` and `then()` methods of your mocked context. It is actually described in example of [official tutorial here.](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html)

```
@Mock
Context mMockContext;

@Test
public void readStringFromContext_LocalizedString() {
    // Given a mocked Context injected into the object under test...
    when(mMockContext.getString(R.string.hello_word))
            .thenReturn(FAKE_STRING);
    ClassUnderTest myObjectUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(mMockContext);

    // ...when the string is returned from the object under test...
    String result = myObjectUnderTest.getHelloWorldString();

    // ...then the result should be the expected one.
    assertThat(result, is(FAKE_STRING));
```

Comment: Why is my `mMockContext.getString(R.string.hello_word)` null?

Comment: Because it's mock context. It's not real. So you have to tell your fake context what to return if someone asks for a string. Use that when-then pattern BEFORE you need to get the string.